# Dota start and crash with this log

Tags: games, steam

Dota start and crash with this log

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
/bin/sh\0-c\0/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=570 -- /home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta/game/bin/win64/dota2.exe' -steam +voice_fadeouttime 0 -prewarm_panorama -novid  -gl -vulkan\0
chdir "/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/intro/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

Comment: 1. A error log is not a question. 2. You might find help at https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Besides you only providing what appears to be a *paste* without an actual question, we don't know Ubuntu product & release you're using; the starting point for providing help.